# Multiple MIDI.js Players on single page?

Tags: javascript, midi.js

Is it possible to have two or more `MIDI.js` `Player`'s on a page?

This seems to create and then populate only one MIDI object, regardless of how many elements of class `nmidiplayer` there are:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                                             
    $('.nmidiplayer').each(npMIDIPlayer);
});

function npMIDIPlayer(idx, elem) {
    var midi = MIDI;
    // ....
}
```

Please, it it possible with `MIDI.js`? How?

Comment: Isn't just about creating another instance of a `Player`?

Comment: @Nonemoticoner, please, how to initialize just another instance? I am not a programmer, I'm trying to solve this in a way I understand now, but no success. Thank you.

Comment: I believe you need another `MIDI` object. Here's how to achieve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: But without understanding JavaScript you will surely face many more problems later anyway.

Comment: @Nonemoticoner, if I was a programmer, I would hardly consider cloning of already existing objects as a proper way of creating new instances (not clones). So, if this is the only possibility for `MIDI.js` --- I do rather not need to have multiple players.

Comment: `Player` is an object that belongs to `MIDI` object and you could maybe copy only that `Player` to have another "playing machine". Yet, it most probably rely on some other properties belonging to `MIDI` object and so by this `Player` wouldn't work properly. It is only a matter of doubling amount of memory needed for a program.